# How can I handle the calling of a function with two objects that implement different interfaces in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following interfaces:

```
interface Ixy 
{
    X: string;
    Y: string;
}
interface Ixz 
{
    X: string;
    Z: string;
}
```

This function:

```
export function update(json: Ixy) {
    var a = json.X;
}
```

The function is called from the following two places:

```
export function update1(json: Ixy) {
   update(json);
}
export function update2(json: Ixz) {
   update(json);
}
```

Can someone explain to me the best way I cand make this work with typescript. Right 
now update1 is okay but update2 shows that the signature does not match. Is the only
way I can fix this to change the type of the json to any or is there a better way to
do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do it. Probably the best is to create a base interface `Ixx` which has the common property `X`, then extend it to create `Ixy` and `Ixz`, and then implement `update` with `Ixx` as the parameter type:

```
interface Ixx 
{
    X: string;
}

interface Ixy extends Ixx
{
    Y: string;
}
interface Ixz extends Ixx
{
    Z: string;
}

export function update(json: Ixx) {
    var a = json.X;
}

export function update1(json: Ixy) {
   update(json);
}
export function update2(json: Ixz) {
   update(json);
}
```

This works because `Ixy` and `Ixz` both extend `Ixx` and so would satisfy the condition `json is Ixx`. This works with classes extending a base class as well (or classes which extend a base interface).

There's not a lot of literature on TypeScript yet, so perhaps a couple of general introductions to interfaces from other languages will be useful, as this is really a cross-language question about interface use, rather than anything TS-specific.

Java interfaces: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html

C# interfaces: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18743/Interfaces-in-C-For-Beginners

Comment: This looks very good. What is the other way you are thinking of ?

Comment: Much uglier. Change the signature of update to `update(X:string);` and then call it using `update(json.X);`  I think extending an interface is a lot better: you can put any number of common attributes on to the base interface then, and pass them efficiently to `update()`.